# Resizing columns bug in Material-UI X-Grid when using in RTL

Tags: material-ui, datagrid, resize

Resizing columns does not work properly when using Material UI X-Grid component with RTL theme.

Accepted- dragging the LEFT portion of the column separator to the left will *expand* the column. 
Actual- dragging the LEFT portion of the column separator to the left *shrinks* the column.

How can I fix it?

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-fuhik?file=/demo.js)

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can just wrope it with  tag like this:

```
<div style={{direction:'rtl'}}>
    ...
</div>
```

Then your dragging portion is correct but MUI has a bug there so it's not dragging correctly.